# Functional way to find item in array from a previous index

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects

Something like

```
const items: item[] = [
    {id: 1, type: 'parent'},
    {id: 2, type: 'parent'},
    {id: 3, type: 'child'},
    {id: 4, type: 'child'},
]
```

Now I want to make a function that if given an item of type `child` it returns the first preceding row with type `parent`.

I want to do this a more functional way for education purposes. I've done this imperatively as such (pseudo-code, but should work):

```
function getParentItem(item: item)
    let startIndex = items.indexOf(item)
    let item = null
    while(!item){
        if(items[startIndex].type == "parent"){
            item = items[startIndex]
        }
        startIndex--
    }
    return item
}
getParentItem({id: 4, type:'child'}) //Should return {id: 2, type: 'parent'}
```

What would be a good, immutable, functional way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure you don't recreate the elements of your array as you did in your example. Since you're changing the reference, the indexOf function will not be able to find it. A better approach is to use the `findIndex` index, which receives a matcher function. It'll return the index of the first element this function resolves to `true`.

Then, you can use `findLast`, which does the same, but instead of returning for the first matching element index, it will search for the last matching element and return **it** instead of the index. Also, the matcher functions receive the index of the current checked element so that you can limit it.

```js
const items = [
    {id: 1, type: 'parent'},
    {id: 2, type: 'parent'},
    {id: 3, type: 'child'},
    {id: 4, type: 'child'},
]

function getParentItem(elementId) {
  const elementIndex = items.findIndex(el => el.id === elementId);
  if (elementIndex === -1) return null;
  const parentItem = items.findLast((el, index) => index < elementIndex && el.type === 'parent');
  return parentItem || null;
}

console.log(getParentItem(3)) // { id: 2, type: parent }
console.log(getParentItem(4)) // { id: 2, type: parent }
console.log(getParentItem(5)) // null
console.log(getParentItem(2)) // { id: 1, type: parent }
console.log(getParentItem(1)) // null
```

Another approach may be more performant (haven't tested it), but you can write your find function, which will iterate fewer cycles than the `findLast` function, and in fact, it will go backward from the current element.

```js
function findReversed(array, fromIndex, matcherFunction) {
    for (let i = fromIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const currentItem = array[i];
        if (matcherFunction(currentItem)) {
            return currentItem; // Note how we return the value of the function here, it will not proceed to other items.
        }
    }
}
```

And your final result will look something like that.

```js
const items = [
    {id: 1, type: 'parent'},
    {id: 2, type: 'parent'},
    {id: 3, type: 'child'},
    {id: 4, type: 'child'},
]

function findReversed(array, fromIndex, matcherFunction) {
    for (let i = fromIndex - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        const currentItem = array[i];
        if (matcherFunction(currentItem)) {
            return currentItem; // Note how we return the value of the function here, it will not proceed to other items.
        }
    }
}

function getParentItem(elementId) {
  const elementIndex = items.findIndex(el => el.id === elementId);
  if (elementIndex === -1) return null;
  const parentItem = findReversed(
    items, 
    elementIndex, 
    el => el.type === 'parent'
  );
  return parentItem || null;
}

console.log(getParentItem(3)) // { id: 2, type: parent }
console.log(getParentItem(4)) // { id: 2, type: parent }
console.log(getParentItem(5)) // null
console.log(getParentItem(2)) // { id: 1, type: parent }
console.log(getParentItem(1)) // null
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that [`Array.prototype.findLast`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findLast#browser_compatibility=) isn’t supported on Firefox yet and for Node.js only available in v18.5.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getParentItem(item){
  
    let startIndex = items.findIndex((ele,index)=>ele.id==item.id)
    let obj=null;
    while(obj==null && startIndex>=0){
      if(items[startIndex].type=="parent"){
        obj=items[startIndex]
        break;
      }else{
        startIndex--
      }
    }
    return obj
}


console.log(getParentItem({id: 4, type:'child'}))
```

Use this function .

Comment: There is no need to pass a whole object if you check only for the id. Also, instead of storing a temporary value in the `obj` variable and breaking the loop by `break`, you can return the `items[startIndex]`.

Comment: yes , but I made the solution similar to Question

Answer (score 0):

You can [find the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) of the child and then [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the array based on this index and finally [reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the sliced array and [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the first matching parent item.

```js
function getFirstPrecedingParent(items, childId) {
  const childIndex = items.findIndex(({ id }) => id === childId);
  return items
    .slice(0, childIndex !== -1 ? childIndex : 0)
    .reverse()
    .find(({ type }) => type === "parent");
}
const items = [
  { id: 1, type: "parent" },
  { id: 2, type: "parent" },
  { id: 3, type: "child" },
  { id: 4, type: "child" },
];
console.log(getFirstPrecedingParent(items, 4));
```

In TypeScript:

```
interface Item {
  id: number;
  type: string;
}
function getFirstPrecedingParent(
  items: Item[],
  childId: number
): Item | undefined {
  const childIndex = items.findIndex(({ id }) => id === childId);
  return items
    .slice(0, childIndex !== -1 ? childIndex : 0)
    .reverse()
    .find(({ type }) => type === "parent");
}
const items: Item[] = [
  { id: 0, type: "child" },
  { id: 1, type: "parent" },
  { id: 2, type: "parent" },
  { id: 3, type: "child" },
  { id: 4, type: "child" },
];
console.log(getFirstPrecedingParent(items, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing you can’t do without `reduce` :)

```js
const items = [
    {id: 1, type: 'parent'},
    {id: 2, type: 'parent'},
    {id: 3, type: 'child'},
    {id: 4, type: 'child'},
]

const getParentItem = ({id}) => items.reduce(
    ([parent, done], item) =>
        done || item.id === id
            ? [parent, true]
            : [item.type === 'parent' ? item : parent, false],
    [undefined, false]
)[0]
 
console.log(getParentItem({id: 4, type: 'child'}))
```

Please don’t use this. I just did this for fun. It’s pretty unreadable and there are much better ways of doing this, such as [r0den’s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926276/8289918) or [SSM’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926390/8289918).